# Looking for a short story about man's planned invasion of Mars (or reverse), which fails because of bureaucratic lack of funding

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I recall reading this story when I was much younger, in Spanish, and I think it was some sort of adaptation/translation.  At the time I thought it was great.  Later on, upon reading Mr. Bradbury's Martian Chronicles, I remembered it because of the similarity to his stories.  In the Spanish version I remember, either the human expedition/invasion to/of Mars (or the Martian expedition/invasion to/of Earth) have to be cancelled because of bureaucratic lack of funding.

Note: I am looking for the original story, NOT the Spanish translation/adaptation.

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/) and see if you can [edit] in any more details.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've read that story.  Did the other side invade at the end and find the records of the bureaucratic back-and-forth?

Comment: @EmsleyWyatt: You are absolutely right.  In fact, I think it definitely Loophole by Mr. Clarke, as Jeremy French has indicated.

Comment: @ltcomdata thanks. If you are happy with the answer you can mark it as correct with the tick, to mark the question as answered and so others may be able to find in future

Comment: See OP confirmation comment above.

Answer (score 4):

I think it may be [Loophole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loophole_(short_story)) by Arthur C. Clarke.

Synopsis ([from here](http://arthur-clarke-fansite.blogspot.co.uk/2007/05/loophole-government-bureaucracy-doing.html)):

> They decide to act. Several Martian spaceships reach earth, & issue a warning: stick to earth, or face the consequences. No rockets & space exploration allowed for such violent beings.
>
> We are told of above proceedings in the form of memos moving around in Martian bureaucracy - usually with very comic contents.
>
> In the final act, we see the Martian civilization decimated.

It may not be it, but as your description is a little vague it is worth mentioning.

Hat tip to @Emsley Wyatt for triggering my memory.

Comment: The original story is available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/Astounding_v37n02_1946-04_cape1736#page/n55/mode/2up).

Comment: I thought that was it but the "standout feature" to me was the use of teleportation, not the bureaucratic aspect.